# Restrict access to WordPress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Is there a way that I can restrict access to url calls made to WP REST API? I am using WP REST API to create AJAX feeds that can be accessed through the URL. They are formatted like this: `http://example.com/wp-json/posts?type=post&filter[posts_per_page]=10`

The problem is that anyone can add `/wp-json/posts?type=post&filter[posts_per_page]=10` to the end of my URL and retrieve a feed of this information. I want to turn this off when users are not logged into WordPress doing something like this:

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
    // Turn off REST API feed
}
```

Or, I would like to add some kind of authentication that needs to be added to mask the api.

I found something like this online but I have not had any luck getting it to work. I added it to a custom plugin. Unfortunately I am still able to access the feed when not logged in.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $wp_post_types['post']->show_in_rest = is_user_logged_in();
}, 20 );
```

I am worried that there is no way to make a connection between activating the API and making the HTTP request on the front end. Am I thinking about this wrong? Has anyone run into this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to access the API from the same server/site, or from an external site?

Comment: It will be from the same site and server.

Answer (score 8):

The problem and blessing of Wordpress is that it allows too much flexibility, particularly when the platform provides a clean method: [Require Authentication for all requests](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#require-authentication-for-all-requests)

> You can require authentication for all REST API requests by adding an
>   is_user_logged_in check to the [rest_authentication_errors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_authentication_errors/) filter.
>
> Note: The incoming callback parameter can be either null, a WP_Error,
>   or a boolean. The type of the parameter indicates the state of
>   authentication:
>
> - null: no authentication check has yet been performed, and the hook callback may apply custom authentication logic.
> - boolean: indicates a previous authentication method check was    performed. Boolean true indicates the request was successfully
>     authenticated, and boolean false indicates authentication failed.
> - WP_Error: Some kind of error was encountered.

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    // If a previous authentication check was applied,
    // pass that result along without modification.
    if ( true === $result || is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }

    // No authentication has been performed yet.
    // Return an error if user is not logged in.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'rest_not_logged_in',
            __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ),
            array( 'status' => 401 )
        );
    }

    // Our custom authentication check should have no effect
    // on logged-in requests
    return $result;
});
```

To be fair, this is hidden in the frequently asked questions.

Edit: To exclude jwt-auth

```
global $wp;

// No authentication has been performed yet.
// Return an error if user is not logged in and not trying to login.
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $wp->request !== 'wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token' ) {
    return new WP_Error(
        'rest_not_logged_in',
        __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ),
        array( 'status' => 401 )
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it works fine. 
BUT:
This stops my addon  CONTACT FORM 7 from working!

I use this as a contact form for users that are not logged in.
The addon tries to access
/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/9589/feedback

and this is blocked by your code.
How cat I avoid this?

Comment: @CSharper I have some routes where I do want to allow unauthenticated users to go to, like the `wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` route above. So just replace that route with yours

Answer (score 5):

This will remove all REST API endpoints for WordPress and Woocommerce for not logged in users:

```
function myplugin_removes_api_endpoints_for_not_logged_in() {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

        // Removes WordpPress endpoints:
        remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_initial_rest_routes', 99 );

        // Removes Woocommerce endpoints
        if ( function_exists('WC') )
            remove_action( 'rest_api_init', array( WC()->api, 'register_rest_routes' ), 10 );
    }

} add_action('init', 'myplugin_removes_api_endpoints_for_not_logged_in');
```

Comment: You can add it to your `functions.php` file, that would do it.

Comment: how can I login using nextjs app then ??

Answer (score 1):

This will block the entire REST API for anyone not logged in:

```
function no_valid_user_no_rest($user) {
    if (!$user) {
        add_filter('rest_enabled', '__return_false');
        add_filter('rest_jsonp_enabled', '__return_false');
    }
    return $user;
}
add_filter('determine_current_user', 'no_valid_user_no_rest', 50);
```

Standard caveat that this just turns off REST, nothing else.  Make sure it has enough priority to come after other `determine_current_user` filters. Did not test on multi site.

You can add other tests to the conditional as well, if you want to filter by URL or other factors.

Comment: Garbage. I still get users list from requesting: `http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users`.

Comment: @TuninTuna make sure you are not logged in before testing

Comment: Thanks for your response holmes, I managed to do this in a different way, maybe in a way that wasn't available at the time of this question. I'll post it below for reference.

Comment: how can I login using nextjs app then ??